# Read input from user and store it to a variable using subprocess

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to read input from the user and store it in a variable by using `subprocess.check_output` in python2.7. But it shows up the error `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` when I try to run it. Also it is to be noted that I strictly want to use `shell=False` because of the security concerns.

I have tried `subprocess.Popen` and it doesnt work that way too.
I have tried to use `sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty', 'r')` and `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` but give the same error as above.

```
>>> import sys
>>> import subprocess
>>> sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty', 'r')
>>> cmd = ('read userinput && echo "$userinput"')
>>> confirmation = subprocess.check_output(cmd.split(), stdin=sys.stdin).rstrip()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 567, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The expected result is that it should ask for user input and store it to the `confirmation` variable

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not using `input()`?

Comment: Actually I am using this in a `pre_push_hook.py` file which is a git hook. So when the script runs it is kind of copied to the `.git/hooks` directory and it runs in a git console. So when I tried to use `input()` (or `raw_input()`), it gave 'EOFError'.
Actually I just tried and putting `   
 `sys.stdin.flush()` and `sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty', 'r')` did the trick and `raw_input()' worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

You are entering a shell command (`read` and `echo` are shell built-ins, and `&&` is shell syntax), therefore you need `shell=True`.  This is a single shell command, so you don't use the `split`.  The parentheses around the command in python have no effect in this case:

```
import sys
import subprocess
sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty', 'r')

cmd = 'read userinput && echo "$userinput"'
confirmation = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stdin=sys.stdin, shell=True).rstrip()

print'****', confirmation
```

Gives:

```
$ python gash.py
hello
**** hello
```

Comment: Hi @cdarke, Thanks for your answer.
But I strictly need `shell=False` as there are security considerations; do you know any method I could do to perform my desired task?

Comment: What security considerations that don't apply to python scripts too?  Bottom line is that you can't execute a shell command without using a shell.

Comment: there are security considerations as also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)